# Where to place sql query in ffmpeg php code to fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql, ffmpeg

I am working on `ffmpeg php` . In the code it is fetching id3 tag from the mp3 file that is in xamp directory.I want to fetch the id3 tags information directly from database. Kindly help me where should i Place sql query to fetch it from database.This is the code I am working on : 
[Code of ffmpeg](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/482-PHP-Extracts-attributes-of-audio-files-Visualization.html#view_files/files/1582)

Comment: Please don't paste code as image.

Comment: Its not image.It is the link where code is written.u can.copy paste from there

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please try to post the code directly. Just copy it in, then highlight it and press ctrl -K  for indentation. Also take a look at [mcve] which is a help page that explains how to present a question, so people will look at it. It's important to make it easy for others to help,